# Performance issues on Lenovo T460s (seems like graphics problem under metacity)

Tags: unity, 15.10, intel-graphics, thinkpad, metacity

We just got new **Lenovo Thinkpad T460s** laptops at work.

```
Processor:  4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 
Graphics:   Intel HD Graphics 520
Memory:     8055MB DDR4
Harddisk:   256 GB SSD (Samsung)
```

I installed `Ubuntu 15.10.` alongside `Windows 7`. So far everything works; apart from the docking station, but that's another [story](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/49oelo/t460_pro_dock_ubuntu_freeze_with_dp_monitor/). (I 
am not sure whether it is relevant, however, a second screen is connected 
to the laptop via hdmi-to-dvi.)

However, it seems like the **system does not use its full potential**. The
windows under Ubuntu do not move smoothly. Furthermore, it feels like every action has a certain latency (it's not much, but enough to
notice). I installed the `gnome-session-flashback` package. However,
both under `compiz` and `metacity` I got the same problems. I even tried
to remove all relevant effects using the `Compiz config settings manager` as well as the `Unity tweak tool`. Still the same problems.

I am not sure what to look for.

So first thing we did was to get a `glmark2` benchmark score. It is only **79** (the whole output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/AhK1Fti1)).
This seems to be quite low (see here for [comparison](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131425); furthermore a five
year old T410 -- without a dedicated GPU and a i7-M620 @ 2.6GHz CPU --
got a score of 146). It seems that something with the graphic
acceleration does not work right.

The `glxinfo` dump can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/a1aj6Xfm).

---

**Edit:**

I did not mention that I run `glmark2` under `metacity` because I thought it shouldn't make any difference. However, it does! `glmark2` under `unity` gives a score of 1009. However, the windows still do not move as smoothly under `unity` as they could (in my opinion).

---

Is there any idea what to do or where to look next? Any help would be
greatly appreciated.

Do not hesitate to ask if you need more information from me.

**Summary:**

- Ubuntu 15.10 GUI does not run smoothly on a high performance laptop
- Very low glmark2 score: 79 (at least under `metacity`)

Ps.:
I just ran the Win 7 internal performance benchmark and got an overall score of 6.7 (max score you can get is 7.9). However, I also find that the  windows are somehow lagging when moved around. I wonder whether this is either a general problem of T460s laptops or my exaggerated expectations.

Comment: A good test of this is pressing the "full screen" button on a YouTube video - the fancy fade that it does is very, very slow - it's several seconds before the video shows up full screen, and also several seconds lag occur between moving the mouse and the video controls appearing on screen. It seems like anything involving a "fade" is very very slow - including the fade out when you close a detail view of a tweet on the Twitter web app.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the advice I'd seen elsewhere - removing the Intel driver and thus falling back on the modesetting driver built into Xorg.

Upside : the YouTube "fade" transition is much faster. Something has changed. It is still, however, not smooth or fast.

Downside : Not sure if this just because I restarted a browser session with about 30 windows in it shortly after removing the driver and rebooting, but it provoked the first time this laptop has actually built up enough heat to start the fan. Going to try this out for a while to see if this is a general trend.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. What kernel version are you using? I am just waiting to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.4. I am rather risk avers since this is my productive system I use at work at the moment. I am not sure whether it is really necessary to switch to the newest mainline kernel. There are some threads that indicate that manifold problems could occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop freezes after connecting external monitor, since 16.04 update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762373/laptop-freezes-after-connecting-external-monitor-since-16-04-update)

Answer (score 2):

My T460s shipped with the graphics memory turned down to 256MB in the BIOS setup. Go in there and crank it up to 512. When I did that, the UI sluggishness I experienced went away.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating to latest-ish kernel. I also had to add "intel_pstate=no_hwp" to my grub cmdline

Comment: The most recent kernel fixes the "close the lid and it crashes" bug that the no_hwp line worked around - but does this have any other impact on the performance problem mentioned?