# Unable to use external monitor in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 16.04LTS with Windows 10 on an ASUS UX305U Zenbook. It's got a Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 & a Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) GPU

This laptop only has a micro-HDMI port, and I'm trying to connect it to an external monitor by using a micro-HDMI to VGA dongle. The issue is that the micro-HDMI port isn't detecting the port being connected.

I tried doing the standard

> Settings > Displays > Detect Displays

and that did nothing.

I know the dongle is okay because the Windows partition can use it fine. I was thinking it might be a graphics driver problem, but I'm not so sure. I think that 16.04 ships with the latest drivers anyways. Just in case I'll include the output of lshw -c video.

So basicly: Is anyone else experiencing something like this? What else should I try?

I'd really appreciate some help.

[lshw -c video output (w/dongle in monitor & laptop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhBoj.png)

[xrandr output (with the dongle plugged into both the laptop and the monitor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkaNO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I managed to fix it and everything is working well!

I just changed my kernal to 4.4.8 and Now I'm good to go!

http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

This article should get you setup. Just follow the instructions, and reboot your machine into the new kernal. Plug in your monitor AFTER your machine has booted, and do the standard

> System Settings > Displays > Detect displays

The thread "[Laptop freezes after connecting external monitor, since 16.04 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762373/laptop-freezes-after-connecting-external-monitor-since-16-04-update?rq=1)" thread was where the solution came from, so big thanks to Louis-Rémi for putting it up

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The cause in my problem was that "UEFI secure boot" was enabled, and that prevents loading of third-party kernel modules. Once I disabled, it went back into working.
The following link was helpful -
 [Disabling UEFI on a running Ubuntu system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815252/disabling-uefi-on-a-running-ubuntu-system) !