# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, cuda

I just installed CUDA in a notebook like this:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Like said [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation).

The compilation works just fine but when I try to run I got the followin problem:

```
CUDA error at file.cu:128 code=35(cudaErrorInsufficientDriver) "cudaStreamCreate(&(stream[i]))"
```

My nvcc version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

Graphics card info:

```
lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
```

I also installed `VirtualGL`, `bumblebee-nvidia`, `primus`, `freeglut3-dev`.
Following [this](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?21956-%28Guide%29-Installing-Nvidia-Bumblebee-CUDA-for-Optimus-enabled-Laptops).

When I try to run something on bumblebee I got this:
optirun glxspheres64

```
[   41.413478] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[   41.413520] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

nvidia driver not working.

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

It looks like the nvidia 375 version is instaled but I can't make it works.

```
whereis nvidia
nvidia: /usr/lib/nvidia /usr/share/nvidia /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.66/nvidia
```

And some driver info.

```
modinfo nvidia_375
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-54-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_375.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        375.66
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     68751AFD79A210CEFFB8758
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        
vermagic:       4.8.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UpdateMemoryTypes:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_CheckPCIConfigSpace:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UseThreadedInterrupts:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
```

I think it can be some driver version problem:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                            3.2.1-10                                      amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-375                                  375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.66
ii  nvidia-375-dev                              375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                             375.51-0ubuntu1                               amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-375                       375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how do you install drivers?

Comment: Faced the same error, and none of the answers worked. What did work was a simple: `$ reboot now`.

Comment: @darthbhyrava that does not work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution by Markus lead me to a better solution. So it has to do with Secure Boot, but it is not necessary to deactivate.

To fix the problem, just do 3 steps: Deactivate the Nvidia driver by choosing X.Org with the Additional Drivers tool, reboot, then activate the Nvidia driver, reboot and enroll the key in Secure Boot.

Usually when you activate the Nvidia driver with the Additional Drivers tool, you are asked for a (new) password for Secure Boot. After reboot, the PC jumps into Secure Boot settings and you are asked to enroll a new MOK key, which must be confirmed with that same password. Afterwards, the driver will get access to the Nvidia card and will work.

Comment: Ubuntu asks for a MOK, and strangely enough, never recognizes the password.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped above o.O – yes it's MOK not ROK. You have to enter a new password that you have to think up, and which you will then only need once for secure boot setup (enroll new MOK key in BIOS).

Comment: I only needed to reboot once at the end (after switching back to the NVIDIA driver)

Comment: (+1) this worked for me. Thanks. In case the Secure Boot password isn't known beforehand, I uninstalled the NVIDIA driver using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and then re-installed it by clicking on the `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary)` radio button in the "Additional drivers" tab in the "Software & Updates" Ubuntu app. During re-installation, it asks you to create a Secure Boot password, which is the same password that I entered during the "Enroll MOK" step after reboot.

Answer (score 37):

You may want to install cuda toolkit. Using the following command to install it.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Once the installation is done, reboot the machine. `nvidia-smi` should work.

Comment: It didn't work here

Comment: don't do this if you have cuda >= 10. It will downgrade your cuda to 9, that is available currently on ubuntu without  CUDA PPA.

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` before, then the above line fixed everything CUDA related for me, installed 430 driver with CUDA 10.1

Comment: made no difference

Comment: Rebooting did the trick

Comment: I did this, then "sudo reboot". Then "sudo prime-select nvidia" and "sudo reboot".

Comment: I did what you said, and got: ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-111:~$ nvidia-smi
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.216.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470         # version 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510         # version 510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-515

Comment: @loretoparisi what should one do then?

Answer (score 30):

If your `nvidia-smi` failed to communicate but you've installed the driver so many times, check `prime-select`.

1. Run `prime-select query` to get all possible options. You should see at least `nvidia | intel`.
2. Choose `prime-select nvidia`.
3. If it says `nvidia is already selected`, select a different one, e.g. `prime-select intel`, then switch back to nvidia `prime-select nvidia`
4. Reboot and check `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: uh oh, `prime-select query` didn't even list intel, I guess I have 2 problems now...

Comment: `query` doesn't list all possible options. From the script: 'query: checks which version is currently active and writes "nvidia", "intel" or "unknown" to the standard output'.

Comment: Does not work. Same problem persists.

Comment: message says `the nvidia profile is already set` (I have already rebooted so it does not work)

Comment: @KansaiRobot did you solve it ?

Comment: `prime-select nvidia` gives: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/prime-select", line 458, in <module>
    switcher.enable_profile(arg)
  File "/usr/bin/prime-select", line 223, in enable_profile
    if not self._has_integrated_gpu():
  File "/usr/bin/prime-select", line 198, in _has_integrated_gpu
    if t.find('8086') != -1 or t.lower().find('1002') != -1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't' referenced before assignment
`

Comment: I get: Error: no integrated GPU detected

Answer (score 19):

I disabled the Secure Boot and it worked pretty fine.

@rod-smith aswered [another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815252/disabling-uefi-on-a-running-ubuntu-system) question more specific explaining how to do it, basically is a setup config, but he also write a good article about how to do that in [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable).

Comment: It helped me to with nvidia driver 390 also! I never thought it might be because of secure boot, thx :)

Comment: UEFI Mode with Secure Boot desabled is already done here. =) Looks like it does not works for everyone, unfortunately.

Comment: Secure Boot is the thing, but no need to deactivate! When activating the Nvidia driver, you must to enter a secure boot password; then reboot and import the new ROK key with that password in Secure Boot settings. Now the driver is active.

Comment: "My front door was getting stuck in the frame. I removed the lock and it worked pretty fine."

Comment: That's the one that worked for me. I changed the CMOS battery of the motherboard; on reboot I got "bad" graphics and no CUDA. After disabling Secure Boot, everything went back to normal. Haven't tried the suggestion of @w-sky, though. Maybe it's better.

Comment: That was my case, too. And my name is Rodolfo, too.

Answer (score 12):

since I cannot comment on @Rodolfo's answer above (not enough reputation), I am adding a new answer.

On my machine I had to configure *Secure Boot* accordingly to my OS. I have an ASUS mainboard running Ubuntu 18.04 and tried to install NVIDIA CUDA 10.1 Update 2 with the packaged NVIDIA driver. I faced the same issue as described above. As it turned out, *Secure Boot* was set to Windows UEFI mode. Changing it to *Other OS* fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, I had to disable `Secure Boot` which was automatically re-enabled during a Windows/BIOS auto-update!!! Now nvidia works fine.

Comment: would you mind explaining how you changed the secure boot to *Other OS* ?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for a solution for **Google Cloud Platform**, it is best to follow the advice of Google and only use recommended Ubuntu version (at the time of writing May 2020 use either 16.04 or 18.04, the new 20.04 is not yet supported) and follow the official instructions for installing CUDA support for Google Cloud VM [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#ubuntu-driver-steps). This will give you the **correct version** of the driver that works with GCP VM. Then restart the instance with `sudo reboot` or from console.

If you are installing CUDA for GCP VM any other way you may still succeed but struggle with issues like "*NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver*" or some dependency problem.

PS! I will not copy the instructions here as they are prone to change any time, always refer to original GCP source for the latest working solution.

Comment: If you're using Deep Learning VM and if `nvidia-smi` worked earlier, this might help to reinstall the default version again: `sudo /opt/deeplearning/install-driver.sh`

Comment: The above comment is such an under appreciated comment, thanks @GokulNC

Answer (score 0):

A lot of users have mentioned that they are unable to install the Nvidia-toolkit, and `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` doesn't work.
Be sure to check that you are using the latest GCC compiler. Using an older GCC compiler like 4.9 will not be able to compile the Nvidia Cuda toolkit. Try installing after using the latest GCC compiler, such as v9.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete solution that worked for me.
https://www.murhabazi.com/install-nvidia-driver

don't forget to disable secure boot.

Answer (score -1):

For future readers:

> I am on a virtual machine instance (Google Cloud Platform)

and I am following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73) to install `Cuda` and `CuDNn` on my VM.

I had to manually upload the `CuDNn` part. (Just putting it out there.)

**Now, getting to the error:**

I was having this issue but a complete restart of the instance did the job.
And by complete restart I mean stopping the instance and turning it back on again.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: it did not work for me.

Comment: Linus Torvalds once said "F*** You, NVIDIA !!" To this day, I suppose his/this statement.

Comment: Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36yNWw_07g&ab_channel=Kuttofos

Answer (score -1):

I was using driver version 470 in Ubuntu 20.04 (latest driver at time of writing).

I went to Software & Updates>Additional Drivers, then downgraded to nvidia-driver-460, clicked Apply, then rebooted.

After that I was able to to see the correct output from `nvidia-smi` again.

Comment: Did not help for my Ubuntu 20.04.