# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize second monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and it is not recognizing my second monitor

I have already executed the following commands (I believe that only these worked in version 19.10):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

the video driver I'm using is nvidia-driver-440

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.03  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

sudo lshw -C display

```
*-display
   descrição: VGA compatible controller
   produto: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
   fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation
   ID físico: 0
   informações do barramento: pci@0000:01:00.0
   versão: a1
   largura: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuração: driver=nvidia latency=0
   recursos: irq:16 memória:de000000-deffffff memória:c0000000-cfffffff memória:d0000000-d1ffffff porta de E/S:e000(tamanho=128) memória:df000000-df07ffff
*-display
   descrição: VGA compatible controller
   produto: HD Graphics 630
   fabricante: Intel Corporation
   ID físico: 2
   informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
   versão: 04
   largura: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuração: driver=i915 latency=0
   recursos: irq:129 memória:dd000000-ddffffff memória:b0000000-bfffffff porta de E/S:f000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
```

The monitor works normally in Windows.

The computer 'is a Dell inspiron 15 gaming.

Could you help me solve this problem?

## EDIT

Adding maybe helpful information

dmesg (error on 3.413227)

```
[    2.771157] input: Intel HID events as /devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input21
[    2.771351] intel-hid INT33D5:00: platform supports 5 button array
[    2.771385] input: Intel HID 5 button array as /devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input22
[    2.818725] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    2.824516] systemd-journald[357]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    2.861274] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.861718] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    2.867576] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    2.867577] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    2.871051] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Creating sysfs group for PROC_THERMAL_PCI
[    2.877025] IPMI message handler: version 39.2
[    2.877137] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    2.883760] ipmi device interface
[    2.888182] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    2.891093] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    2.894789] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.894802] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    2.894802] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.894805] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.894807] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.894810] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.900899] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.3)
[    2.951677] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[    2.951678] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[    2.951679] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[    2.951680] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[    2.951681] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    2.962398] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/PNP0C14:02/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02/9DBB5994-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492/input/input23
[    2.963189] checking generic (b0000000 7f0000) vs hw (b0000000 10000000)
[    2.963190] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    2.964973] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    2.965012] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    2.968898] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    2.968925] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    2.968926] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    2.970976] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    2.974394] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    3.012062] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (1bcf:28c1)
[    3.021359] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm:intel_dp_aux_init_backlight_funcs [i915]] Panel advertises DPCD backlight support, but VBT disagrees. If your backlight controls don't work try booting with i915.enable_dpcd_backlight=1. If your machine needs this, please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
[    3.030752] uvcvideo 1-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    3.030754] uvcvideo 1-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[    3.030755] uvcvideo 1-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[    3.030756] uvcvideo 1-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    3.030811] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input24
[    3.067420] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    3.138784] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[    3.139119] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.139120] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    3.139121] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    3.139122] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    3.139668] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.139675] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    3.139676] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    3.139719] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.139829] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.140553] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    3.140560] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.146572] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    3.169953] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.169955] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    3.180174] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.180175] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    3.180684] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
[    3.183871] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0007)
[    3.186287] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    3.285843] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.64  Fri Feb 21 01:17:26 UTC 2020
[    3.293163] input: DLL0798:00 06CB:7E92 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DLL0798:00/0018:06CB:7E92.0001/input/input25
[    3.293233] input: DLL0798:00 06CB:7E92 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DLL0798:00/0018:06CB:7E92.0001/input/input26
[    3.293294] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:7E92.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse     [DLL0798:00 06CB:7E92] on i2c-DLL0798:00
[    3.303291] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  440.64  Fri Feb 21 00:43:19 UTC 2020
[    3.338157] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    3.338159] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    3.356373] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 234.
[    3.413227] [drm:lspcon_init [i915]] *ERROR* Failed to probe lspcon
[    3.413265] [drm:intel_ddi_init [i915]] *ERROR* LSPCON init failed on port B
[    3.416312] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1028:0310
[    3.416315] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.416738] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    3.433342] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190822 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    3.438212] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.439099] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input28
[    3.439181] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: no  rom: yes  post: no)
[    3.439215] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0a/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input29
[    3.440445] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.441626] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.441683] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    3.441717] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    3.448458] Adding 19492860k swap on /dev/sdb7.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:19492860k SSFS
[    3.473358] EXT4-fs (sdb6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.485236] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[    3.503143] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.218:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=781 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.504026] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.218:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=774 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.504029] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.218:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=774 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.504031] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.218:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=774 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.504469] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.222:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=777 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.504471] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.222:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=777 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.507632] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.222:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=775 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.507635] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.222:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=775 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.507637] audit: type=1400 audit(1587828434.222:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=775 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.556939] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3246: line_outs=2 (0x14/0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    3.556941] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.556943] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.556944] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.556944] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.556946] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
[    3.556947] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
[    3.556949] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    3.567779] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    3.587279] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.604068] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
[    3.668427] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    3.668428] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    3.668439] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    3.668440] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    3.671748] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.960890] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input31
```

Comment: tried couple of solutions provided here, didnt work for me - so my solution was to simply switch to another desktop environment like KDE Plasma, the problem seemed to only affect the Gnome.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ran into this same issue with nvidia RTX 2060 laptop (MSI GS65). External monitor connected via DisplayPort doesn't show at all through ubuntu settings, but is recognized if I look at nvidia settings. There's a disconnect somewhere.

I downgraded to nvidia-435 driver, and it worked fine. Something didn't get thoroughly vetted/tested with the 440 driver. Just downgrade for now and see if that helps.

Comment: Using version 435 of the driver worked, thank you very much. I hope it doesn't give the same problem with CUDA

Comment: For me this didn't work. However, choosing the open source driver worked!

Comment: Ubuntu and driver issues: https://imgur.com/a/JLWfGfi If you upgrade ubuntu, and a driver in one way or the other, doesn't break, then your upgrade was NOT successful, because a successful Ubuntu upgrade, MUST break something. ALWAYS

Comment: Can verify: I have the same bad behavior with the nvidia-450 driver >:( very frustrating. 

for anyone curious, you can rewake the monitor using xrandr to send a command. For me that was `xrandr --output DP-1-2 --auto`

Comment: proprietary version 450 fixed it for me

Comment: 450 did not fix it for me. Tripple monitors and only one detected in 1024x768 modus.

Comment: For the record, I have a GT 1030, on Xubuntu 20.10. My second monitor will be recognized after booting up with nvidia-driver-450 or 460 in 50% of cases or so, which of course is extremely frustrating. When it is not recognized, `nvidia-settings` just fails. The workarounds that seem to work for me (100% of bootups so far) are using the nouveau driver or using nvidia-driver-390.

Comment: could you please show me how to downgrade it? Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same problem on my laptop (Dell G5 5500 with NVIDIA RTX 2060 as GPU). I solved the problem by **disabling secure boot** in BIOS options.

Comment: Man, you saved my life! thanks!

Comment: This was it for me too! Thanks so much, have been trying everything else for hours now.

Any idea why this is suddenly a problem? Happened for me after the latest bundle of automated package updates of Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Instead of disabling secure boot (which may be necessary in a dual-boot setup), you can also sign the NVidia driver in linux, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue: Yesterday I decided to install my new notebook (ThinkPad P72 with NVIDIA GPU).

First I was happy: there were no problem with the NVIDIA GPU when I installed Ubuntu 20.04. I was happy, since I had an issue with this on Ubuntu 18.04 on another notebook: there I had to switch to the default driver in order to be able to install Ubuntu 18.04 on the system at all or the installation suddenly freezed.

But when I booted Ubuntu 20.04 at home and wanted to connect my notebook to the external monitor for convenience reasons, the usual "Windows+P" shortcut did not work, since it could not detect the external monitor. There was also no second monitor when I opened "Settings-->Displays"

My solution was to go back from NVIDIA driver 440 to 435 by clicking "Activities --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers". Also a restart was needed such that Ubuntu used the 435 driver version.

Now I can choose the monitor to use with "Windows+P" after start and I am using my external monitor right now :)

So it seems the NVIDIA driver 440 has to be updated to work better with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I've just tried this with driver 450 and it works. Thank you!

Comment: When I visit `Activities --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers` I am getting "No Additional Drivers available" error

Comment: I was using the Nouveau driver and had the same issue. I switched to the 418-server package which fixed the issue. How much I wish I had ATI GPU :(

Answer (score 7):

Try this, if not, I'll have my post edited.

Original answer from [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/907907)

"I've recently installed the nvidia-418 driver on my laptop which uses Ubuntu 18.04. At first, the external monitor worked perfectly, but after I switched from power-saving mode (`sudo prime-select intel`) back to performance mode (`sudo prime-select nvidia`), the second monitor was not detected anymore.

I discovered that prime-select writes a configuration file that causes the problem. It enables the nvidia-drm modeset option. You can simply undo the change made by prime-select by commenting out this option. It will not be reset, because prime-select only writes this file when it does not exist yet."

Open the file in your favorite editor (vim, nano, gedit, etc.).

```
sudo nano /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf
```

And comment out the nvidia-drm modeset option.

```
# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
# Set value to 0 to disable modesetting
# options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

"Hope this helps you and many others!

> Normally, the second monitor is not detected by power-saving mode when the connection is part of the Nvidia graphics card."

Comment: I’ve seen it in another question, but it didn’t work, prime was always set to performance mode

Comment: anyway did you commented out the file as a root and checked?

Comment: Try to delete this file, hard reboot, and if not any signal of monitor, try comment this file again.

Comment: Helped for:
nvidia-driver-390 /
Dell e6530 /
Card NVS 5200M /
Ubuntu 20.04.

Before described steps I did:
"sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"

then "modeset=0".
Original NVIDIA link:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-18-04-3-blank-screen-at-startup-with-430-drivers-and-gtx-960/107501#5402308 
also this one is useful:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-19-04-doesnt-detect-my-hdmi-display/79577/22

Also from my side seems that after 
"sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"
just switching to: "nouveau display driver" helped

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue on my laptop dual card (Dell G5 5587) Ubuntu 20.04.

In my case the issue was snapd. ***I have purged and disabled snapd before (that's the fault).***

The issue appear when I use NVIDIA compatible drivers Ex. 435,440,450 with prime on demand or performance mode

That's the issue, because ubuntu 20.04 use combined packages (classical deb and snap)

Solution in my case was the following:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install snap-store
sudo reboot
```

At the end in Settings-Display all the options appear also for the second display (Join, Mirror,Single) and NVidia works again

Comment: how did you identify the problem as `snapd`? seems unrelated?

Comment: if I remove or disable snapd second graphical card and laptop doesn't open video on the laptop main screen (blank after reboot). Works only with internal Intel video card.  Without snapd second videocard doesn't works on laptop display. It works only on secondary.

Comment: Pop!_OS may be a better choice for you then. its Ubuntu LTS based but with no snap. just deb, like in the good ol days. you can add flatpak stuff if you want but its not default

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem right after I changed forced composition pipeline from Nvidia x server settings.

I figured that out if you change anything somehow from Nvidia settings it causes problems.

I **SOLVED** with deleting xorg configuration file: (but before that make sure backup this file)

```
sudo rm -f /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

I deleted this file, then restart the pc, if restart with second monitor connected, there is a graphic glitch on whole screen and locked entire OS. I tried several times with second monitor attached. I realized that when Nvidia starts to working it causes problem. Then i disconnect second monitor and restart. Voila! There is no lock, and connect second monitor after login. Now everything okey.

I really hate that nvidia and intel's graphic collaboration on Ubuntu. I did change force composition choice because i have screen tearing issue, it was solved my problem until i restart thanks nvidia :)

Comment: I was just messing up with steam for linux, and after a game crash, I run into this problem! You save my day, everything is back to normal! Thanks!

Comment: Was suspecting something like this happened, and my hunch was right, never use nvidia-settings to save to xorg.conf, for force composition pipeline, i just added the terminal command that sets it to startup apps now it applies this at every startup without saving to xorg.conf

Comment: After days of fighting this problem, this has solved it for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I have Ubuntu Studio 20.04. I upgraded my ASUS motherboard BIOS and one of my two monitors stopped working. I looked at the output of `dmesg` and it showed this;

```
[ 50.822389] Lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

Some googling showed the the BIOS UEFI safe boot locks the kernel and won't allow the Nvidia drivers to load. Dual boot wont work either with a safe boot. I followed these instructions to remove safe boot https://www.techjunkie.com/disable-secure-boot-asus/ After rebooting both monitors were working.

Answer (score 2):

After struggeling with the same problem with Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming and Ubuntu  20.04 with Mate installed, I read that it might be a problem of drivers I opened the drivers interface:

```
System -> Preferences-> Hardware -> Additional Drivers
```

and changed from **Using X.Org X server** to **Using NVIDIA driver metapackage**:
[image]

Then I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129265/114233) which solved me the problem::

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fix by now. 
Yesterday did check and 440 nvidia driver and PC did recognize dedicated monitor. 
Only thing for me is that, in power saving mode (intel) it doesn't recognise dedicated screen. But it was also with 435 nvidia driver. 
So it could be just for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Ubuntu Kernel to 5.7 or above**

After downgraded to nvidia-435 driver, the problem didn't solve for me. I have searched for some answers and found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240603/second-monitor-not-detected-brightness-not-working-with-nvidia-gtx-1660ti).

The problem is partially solved.  The secondary monitor is working but wifi is not working. *My Laptop is asus zephyrus g14*. So, **I upgraded ubuntu kernel to 5.7 and all are working fine now.**

Download and install Kernel Manually:

```
cd /tmp/

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.0-050700_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_amd64.deb   
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_amd64.deb   
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/amd64/linux-modules-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Once installed, restart your computer and check the system is working on the new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem today with NVIDIA 460 drivers. Ran update and happened to see something I never saw before. A dialog telling me I was using secure boot and that a new key needed to be written to the UEFI. It asked for a new password and a reboot.

Upon reboot I was presented with a really old style blue screen (reminiscent of DOS) asking for the password. I typed it in, rebooted and presto-ubuntu secure booted with all displays working.

Comment: To find out what the blue screen is search for MOK. It is the driver signing needed because of Msoft and Intel collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (couldn't detect 2nd monitor) with HP Pavillion - NVIDIA GTX-1050 with Ubuntu 21.10 in dual boot.

I went to **Applications > Additional Drivers** and saw my default was *Nvidia-driver-470*. I changed it to *X.Org X.Server ... (open source)* and then clicked **Apply Changes**. I then ran the command `sudo reboot`. BOOM, it's working..!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo Legion 5 laptop with RTX Nvidia card and I connected 2 external monitors but only one of them came on. The problem in my case was that I had to switch the input on the monitor itself to HDMI and then it appeared.