# Bad screen quality on new asus notebook

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, brightness, gamma

I bought a new Asus Vivobook. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and when I connected my monitor via HDMI I saw that the screen quality is not so good. The brightness seams to high and the gamma (looks very red-heavy) is also not right.

I have a small second Windows 10 partition, there its looking good. And the quality of the notebook screen itself in Ubuntu is also good!

Before the new Asus I had a Dell Vostro 3750 with Ubuntu 18.04, when I connect the monitor to the old notebook it looks totally fine!

I also tried connecting a different monitor to the Vivobook and there the screen quality is also not good. So it seems not to be an issue with the monitor...

Thanks for any help.

PS: I already found this post: [Second monitor not detected, brightness not working... with Nvidia (GTX 1660ti) and Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.4.0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240603/second-monitor-not-detected-brightness-not-working-with-nvidia-gtx-1660ti)

But the solution with upgrading the kernel has no effect.
I tried 5.8.1 and 5.11.11

**Update 2021-04-08:**

Its very strange, I noticed now two times that the screen suddenly looks good. But I changed nothing (at least not consciously). So it seems to be random. Here are two pictures I took from my screen to compare, when its bad and good:

[good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUg3a.jpg)
[bad image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoSRn.jpg)

**Update 2021-04-10:**

I think now, its maybe not a problem of the second monitor, but a problem of the browser. On Firefox everything looks good, also on the second monitor. But on Chromium, Google Chrome and Brave the colors and brightness is wrong. So its a issue with chrome based browsers?

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with Ubuntu or Windows for that matter, your own comment. You have a hardware problem. I would be having the computer looked at you said it is new.

Comment: Omg, sorry, my bad, I mean on windwos 10 its NOT the same. There it looks good... I
m pretty sure, this is an linux driver/kernel problem.

Comment: Any other ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

Okay very nice, I fixed the issue by editing chrome setting and change force color profile to sRGB!

Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129374/chromium-and-firefox-display-colors-differently-and-i-dont-know-which-one-is-do