# Ubuntu 20.04 with external monitor keeps disconnected

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04

I just switched to 20.04 on my laptop and I am having trouble getting my external monitor working similar to [Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor)

However, I can connect to my monitor...until my computer does to sleep. Once my computer does to sleep, the external monitor does not come back. Once I wake up my laptop, the computer does not cannot find the monitor and will only comeback until I reset my computer.

Does the switch to the old Nvida drivers (435) fix this this problem?