# Dualscreen weird recognize Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.4.0) with NVidia GTX 1660 Ti

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, 20.04

I've just have new laptop from my work and I can't set up the dualscreen. It's not a dualboot, so I can't test on Windows if it works.

Actually my laptop recognizes the second screen however the screen is black and I can just see my mouse on the second screen. Each window can go in this second screen and I can interact with them but the screen is full black.

I tried different options using the nvidia drivers 435 and 440 however in this case I case only interact with the second screen and not the one on the laptop. This is all my tests and results:

- Without Nvidia Drivers: dualscreen recognizes however second screen black but I can interact
- With Nvidia Drivers 440 (recommended by the computer): I can only interact with my second screen and the one on the laptop is full blank
- With Nvidia Drivers 435: no graphics interface.

Here my xrandr with my TV second screen (I'm at home):

```
sophys@sophys-Nitro-AN517-51:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.01    60.02    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i   100.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      60.02    59.80    59.96  
   1920x540      50.04  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00    59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   720x576       50.00  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04    70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
  1920x1080 (0x47) 266.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1920 start 1944 end 1960 total 2000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1111           clock  59.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x48) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1920x1080 (0x49) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4a) 214.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1808 end 1984 total 2288 skew    0 clock  93.86KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1105           clock  84.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4b) 187.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1800 end 1976 total 2272 skew    0 clock  82.31KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1099           clock  74.89Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4c) 174.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1800 end 1976 total 2272 skew    0 clock  76.58KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1096           clock  69.88Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4d) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4e) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x1024 (0x4f) 103.125MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock  60.17Hz
  1400x1050 (0x50) 179.260MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1504 end 1656 total 1912 skew    0 clock  93.76KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1051 end 1054 total 1103           clock  85.00Hz
  1400x1050 (0x51) 155.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1464 end 1784 total 1912 skew    0 clock  81.49KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1090           clock  74.76Hz
  1400x1050 (0x52) 145.060MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1496 end 1648 total 1896 skew    0 clock  76.51KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1051 end 1054 total 1093           clock  70.00Hz
  1400x1050 (0x53) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
  1600x900 (0x54) 246.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1728 end 1900 total 2200 skew    0 clock 111.82KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  59.99Hz
  1600x900 (0x55) 186.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1640 total 1680 skew    0 clock 111.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  926           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x900 (0x56) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x900 (0x57) 97.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.82Hz
  1280x1024 (0x58) 157.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  91.15KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1072           clock  85.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x59) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5a) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x5b) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1400x900 (0x5c) 103.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock  59.96Hz
  1400x900 (0x5d) 86.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x960 (0x5e) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  85.94KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1011           clock  85.00Hz
  1280x960 (0x5f) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x60) 198.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1548 end 1704 total 1968 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x61) 151.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.97Hz
  1368x768 (0x62) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1368x768 (0x63) 72.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.85Hz
  1360x768 (0x64) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0x65) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1280x800 (0x66) 174.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1380 end 1516 total 1752 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  829           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x800 (0x67) 134.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  823           clock  59.97Hz
  1280x800 (0x68) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x800 (0x69) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x6a) 143.470MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1232 end 1360 total 1568 skew    0 clock  91.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  915           clock 100.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x6b) 121.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1568 skew    0 clock  77.49KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  911           clock  85.06Hz
  1152x864 (0x6c) 119.650MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1224 end 1352 total 1552 skew    0 clock  77.09KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  907           clock  85.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x6d) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x6e) 104.990MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1224 end 1352 total 1552 skew    0 clock  67.65KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  902           clock  75.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x6f) 96.770MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1224 end 1344 total 1536 skew    0 clock  63.00KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  70.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x70) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x71) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x72) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x73) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x720 (0x74) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
  1024x768 (0x75) 194.020MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1108 end 1220 total 1416 skew    0 clock 137.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  806           clock  85.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x76) 170.240MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1108 end 1220 total 1416 skew    0 clock 120.23KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  801           clock  75.05Hz
  1024x768 (0x77) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x78) 94.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1168 total 1376 skew    0 clock  68.68KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  808           clock  85.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x79) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x7a) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x7b) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768i (0x7c) 44.900MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1024 start 1032 end 1208 total 1264 skew    0 clock  35.52KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  776 total  817           clock  86.96Hz
  960x720 (0x7d) 170.675MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1036 end 1144 total 1328 skew    0 clock 128.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  756           clock  85.00Hz
  960x720 (0x7e) 148.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1032 end 1144 total 1320 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  75.00Hz
  960x720 (0x7f) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x80) 144.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  992 end 1104 total 1280 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  750           clock  75.00Hz
  928x696 (0x81) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x82) 130.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  944 end 1052 total 1228 skew    0 clock 106.27KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  708           clock  75.05Hz
  896x672 (0x83) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x576 (0x84) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
  1024x576 (0x85) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x576 (0x86) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  1024x576 (0x87) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
  960x600 (0x88) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x89) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
```

and other but I have to reduce my body text ..

Here my displays:

```
sophys@sophys-Nitro-AN517-51:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for sophys: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:160 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:159 memory:b5000000-b5ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Also complementary information:

```
sophys@sophys-Nitro-AN517-51:~$ lspci | grep -A 1 -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Honestly I looking since 2 days for solutions on the net but I didn't understand everything and I couln't find the solution.

Do I have to do something with xorg.conf file?
How can I set a dualscreen on this laptop please?
I look at this thread : [Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor) but I didn't find solutions at my problem.

Comment: Are you directly connecting your monitor HDMI out on laptop to HDMI in on monitor (no adaptors)? And have you tried lowering the refresh rate on the built-in screen? I see the built-in screen has 144Hz capability. I don't know, but perhaps this is causing output/driver issues on the second screen. I would try lowering to 60 or lower and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I connecting directly without any adaptors. Yes I tried to change the refresh rate to 59.96 Hz and that doesn't solve the problem