# Update NVIDIA driver (two cards) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

Is there a way of specifying the device when updating a graphical card driver? In my case I have two graphical cards and driver updates get applied to just one of them Titan Xp. The one that I want to update is the NVIDIA GF119, which is currently stuck in "Manual Install" and I cannot get it updated to a later NVIDIA driver.

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:04:00.1 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000E08sv000010DEsd00001154bc04sc03i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF119 HDMI Audio Controller
driver   : oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms - third-party free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:b2/0000:b2:00.0/0000:b3:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B02sv000010DEsd000011DFbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP102 [TITAN Xp]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:04:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000107Dsv000010DEsd00001154bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF119 [NVS 310]
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
...
```

Any help on how I can manage to update the driver for the GF119 would be greatly appreaciated as I currently cannot connect a second monitor to this card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You already have the most recent version of the proprietary NVIDIA driver that each graphics card supports.**

The misunderstanding is that NVIDIA driver versions support all current and previous cards.

The reason that you cannot update the GF119 (NVS 310) any further is because you are already using the `nvidia-driver-390` driver, which is the most recent driver version for that particular graphics card.

You can verify the most recent driver version available using [NVIDIA's driver download page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

If you use the drop down menus to select the NVS Series 310 using Linux (64-bit) you will see that there are two release channels: "Linux Long Lived" and "Linux Short Lived".  Both of these channels offer the `nvidia-driver-390` as the most recent, which is the version you already have installed.

If you do the same search for your Titan Xp, you will notice that the "Long Lived" driver is `450.66` and the "Short Lived" driver is `435.21`.  You have `nvidia-driver-450` installed, so you also have the most recent driver version for your Titan Xp.

It's possible that NVIDIA is no longer supporting the NVS 310 when releasing newer driver versions.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Nmath. Do you know if that means that I won't be able to enable a second monitor using the extra Displayport on this card? The reason for updating the driver was based on this other question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason why you wouldn't be able to use two displays, but I would suggest using one card for all of your displays. The titan should be able to handle 4 displays so I would suggest plugging both displays into that card. You're kind of asking for trouble trying to use two different cards for the same task unless they are identical.

Comment: The idea was to use the Titan Xp purely as an accelerator for AI. I thought using the old card for monitors would save some extra capacity to train models. However, the monitor overheads must be small, so I'll proceed as you suggested. Thanks for your help