# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize second monitor on Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I followed my own guide in [How to Create a Truly Portable Ubuntu Installation on an External USB HDD or SSD](https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd) to create a portable Ubuntu 20.04 installation, in order to use it with my Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen2 laptop.

However, after booting Ubuntu, a second display (via DP or HDMI) is NOT detected. The NVidia driver under Software and Updates > Additional Drivers - is the nvidia-driver-450 (proprietary, tested) for the GTX 1650 Mobile / MaxQ discrete graphics card.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the full thread in [Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor), and the bug description in 
[[Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 2] HDMI port can't be found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1871573), forcing the BIOS of the laptop to 'discrete' (not hybrid) for the graphics card settings, and disabling secure boot - worked.

The second monitor via either DP or HDMI is detected. What's more, the latest patches for Ubuntu 20.04 seem to have fixed the worst of the fractional scaling issues. Posting here for anyone else that discovers this problem.

Answer (score 1):

My setup

- Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen2 Laptop with NVIDIA Graphics
- Followed this guide to install Ubuntu 20.04 upto the point where you are asked to select the Ubuntu OS i.e

5. Boot Ubuntu from USB
   https://tothepoles.co.uk/2020/05/22/install-notes-ubuntu-20-04-lts-on-lenovo-x1-extreme-gen-2/

- On this point instead of selecting Ubuntu , I selected Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)
- Proceed with the installation steps till you complete the installation and reboot
- Login and Open Additional Drivers
- Select Nvidia driver which is mentioned as Proprietary and Tested which is generally the first option.
- Reboot and second monitor comes up !