# Cannot connect two external monitors. Ubuntu 20.04.02 on ThinkPad-P1-Gen-3

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have recently started using a linux system and I am trying to connect two external monitors using a docking station. I am using Thunderbolt 3 Workstation Dock and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed on my ThinkPad-P1-Gen-3. The issue I am facing is that it recognizes only two monitors and it mirrors the displays on both external monitors. When I connect the monitors directly from my laptop it does identify that there are three displays but one of them is disabled.
I have already installed DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu5.3.1 but it did not help.

Following is the output when two monitors are connected via the docking station. edp-1 is my laptop display

```
~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1-4 1920/476x1080/267+1920+0  eDP-1-4
 1: +eDP-1 1920/344x1080/194+0+0  eDP-1
```

Can someone please help resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor), this was resolved by downgrading the nvidia driver. In my case I downgraded to nvidia-450.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was having the same issues. Then I remember when I on windows it only supported my 2k display and my 1080 display with both at 1080p on both 60 hz. Didn't give me the option to even do the higher resolution on my 2k display when both where plugged in. So this made me think its not a driver issue but rather a resolution issue. SO I googled and found this:

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd029622-display-and-video-output-configurations-docking-stations

SO I set both displays to 1920x1080 60 hz and the worked. But based on the chart from the linkit showed I should be able to run me 2k @ 3840 x 2160 @ 30hz with DP and my second monitor @ 1920 x1080 @ 60 hz. So I tried that and it did not work for me. So maybe try starting with both displays at 1080p.