# ubuntu 22.04 nvidia drivers not working properly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary

So, I have a **GA107M[GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]** and after setup I installed the **nvidia-driver-520** open kernel from additional drivers. PC unable to turn off, screen is glitchy and registering exactly 0,00 Hz and **nvidia-smi** throws an error

```
Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:01:00.0: Not Found
```

after checking additional drivers, I see that the device is using a manually-installed driver, -520 is -525 now and I cannot uncheck the option at the bottom saying **continue using manually installed

---

@ARG: in response to ARG's comment, thank you for the exhaustive list of answers, but that is what I'm trying to say, when entering additional drivers, I have all the options blacked out and cannot uncheck the only available selected option, which is **continue using a manually installed driver**
[this is what I see in Software and updates under additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzpaY.png)

I had previously installed the open-kernel driver from there and it was version-520, upon running **nvidia-detector**, the output is

```
nvidia-driver-525
```

which I did not manually update, so this means it updated automatically and is now causing me problems

Comment: well, when setting up ubuntu, I clicked not to install proprietary drivers, because my research indicated that there could be issues with the nvidia drivers if you select to install additional drivers upon setup and just installed the corresponding latest version, which was -520  and worked well until the driver itself received an update to -525 and I started experiencing those issues

Comment: @Nmath: understood, thank you for the input, if nothing else works, this will be the step I take and I will make sure to install additional drivers upon setup and see if this is true

Answer (score 1):

First I uninstalled current NVidia driver

`sudo apt autoremove nvidia* --purge`

Then installed latest driver from package manager.

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install`

Error reported from running

`sudo nvidia-bug-report.sh`

was

> ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running
> kernel.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files
> for your kernel and that they are properly configured.

This was fixed by running

`sudo apt -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how it was solved. I'm posting my own solution below to give you an idea, please make a backup of your work before trying these steps.

I was using X.Org X server Nouveau display driver on Ubuntu 22.04, Asus rog zephyrus g14, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050. To fix Brave browser freezing issue, I decided to install nvidia-driver-525-open following [GNOME GUI Nvidia Installation Method](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04). After that Ubuntu didn't recognize my external monitor and `nvidia-smi` command output "No devices were found". Then as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385268/764239) I installed nvidia-cuda-toolkit. Problem continued, and all options on Additional Drivers gui disabled except "Continue using a manually installed driver". Then I run `sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-525-open`, `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525` and force rebooted mannualy pressing the button. It worked. My display settings came back again. Brave browser is working without freezing now.