# External monitor not detected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: external-monitor

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot setup with windows 11. I am completely new to Ubuntu and have installed it to learn ROS on it. I am facing the issue of external monitor not being detected. My external monitor (LG 32GK650F) is connected via a working HDMI cable which works perfectly fine in Windows 11. There are no options in Settings>Display for the monitor.

As mentioned, I am completely new to Ubuntu therefore I am completely unknown to basics or what may be considered as a common knowledge for ubuntu ussers. I am unaware of what more information I can provide to assist in solving this issue of mine so please let me know. Thanks!

System specs:
Alienware M15 R7
AMD Ryzen 7 6000H Series
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050Ti (Although, in the about section of the device,it mentions AMD Yellow_carp as its Graphics. I believe this is due to Nvidia X server has configuration of On-Demand Mode)
16 GB RAM

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
GNOME 3.36.8

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor)

You could check for additional drivers. Simply click the menu and search for "drivers." The icon for Additional Drivers comes up and searches automatically when opened.

[image: Additional Drivers window]

If you want to use the command line, open the terminal instead and run:

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

[image: Ubuntu drivers autoinstall]

Comment: Yes, there are no options in additional drivers and I think I completed ubuntu-drivers autoinstall too previously

Comment: I would first try another cable or two. I also notice when this happens to me, it might work to wait till after boot to plug in the HDMI cord. It might work to have it plugged in on boot. If I am booted into another OS using the HDMI port,

Ubuntu doesn't seem to like it when I return and is a bit stubborn about supporting the HDMI port again. Usually, it does not do this, but when it does I try rebooting with it unplugged completely, logging in and rebooting again without plugging the HDMI in at all.

This sort of thing is a crude solution, but I think the issue occurs on boot.

Comment: Also, that makes me wonder if you installed Ubuntu using proprietary drivers?

That might make a difference. If you chose proprietary drivers and install Ubuntu alongside Windows, the installer will ask you to set a password for your hard drive. You must also enable secure boot in BIOS. If you did not do all this, you are using free firmware.

Comment: Bring up `Additional drivers`, then look in the leftmost tab (Ubuntu software) and make sure you have all but `Source` selected; then go back to `Additional drivers`...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments! After solving the issue I had, I realized I was did not switch from on-demand mode in Nvidia x servers to performance mode causing to additional drivers not show up. After switching it to Performance mode, the Additional Drivers were available again and I had plenty of options to choose from. To decide which one was best for me, I went to Nvidia drivers website and plugged in my system information and got the best suited driver recommendation. Then I executed the installation in the Terminal (my apologies if i am using wrong terminology). After that I rebooted the system and to check if it worked, I checked the system information in the about system and it successfully showed NVIDIA Corporation / NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU. And this fixed my external monitor issue.