# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly has become jumpy and less smooth with fan noise

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, performance, fan

My system was running fine for a few days after I installed it. But this morning there is the occasional lag of about 0.25- 0.5 seconds as I am scrolling, typing, highlighting, etc.  E.g. scrolling works for a moment, then suddenly it stops even though I am rolling the mouse wheel, then starts scrolling again. The effect is very subtle and not serious, but annoying.  The same thing happened with Elementary OS every now and again; the problem presented itself then went away, and a few days later it came back again.  I don't know if it may be is the system updating itself in the background, but I cannot find anything to show this.  If anyone knows what it is I would be interested.  I have 16GB RAM and an i7 CPU, NVIDIA graphics card.  I have rebooted, and not changed anything. Many thanks

Comment: When you go into **system settings** > **details,** does it report anything unusual for graphics?

Answer (score 0):

**To determine the problem**, first go into **system settings** > **details** to see if there is anything unusual reported for "graphics."

Also, a good thing to have handy is `htop` running in the terminal so you can see what process is using system resources.

**First**, install htop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install htop
```

and then run:

```
htop
```

or optionally, you can run:

```
sudo htop
```

with full permissions to allow more control (so you can kill processes).

**Additionally**, if you want to try using the proprietary nvidia drivers, you can run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Save any unsaved work and reboot after the installation to apply the changes.

---

Finally, this last step is optional. If you want to use nvidia optimus switching, you can install the bumblebee packages.

**First**, enable the [Universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

**Then**, install the packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic mesa-utils
```

Next, save any unsaved work and then reboot.

**Finally**, run the following command to monitor your nvidia driver:

```
nvidia-smi
```

and run the following command to verify that optimus is running properly:

```
optirun glxgears
```

Now, if you get an error running the last command, [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251346/167115) to properly add your drivers to secureboot.

---

**UPDATE**

It looks like this is a power saving feature. You can monitor CPU performance using the `i7z` tool to verify throttling.

Run the following to install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install i7z
```

and run the tool using the following command:

```
sudo i7z
```

You will see the "actual frequency" listed in the output.

---

You probably won't need to use the following. However, you can [click here for more information about `nvidia-smi`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. I followed your suggested steps. System > details  OK. I installed htop - OK. Updated Nvidia, but said “NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.”. However I think I may have fixed it! I accidently booted into a live USB image of Pop Linux.  I opened browser whilst running the live USB, and the same problem occured. I switched off laptop, disconnected battery and peripherals and rebooted Ubuntu and the problem has gone.  Power management of laptop is at fault, not Ubuntu. Thank you again!

Comment: @DavidWills I used to have a Dell with aggressive power management when the charger was unplugged. Could this be the case? I extended the answer and included i7z, you can use this to monitor CPU frequency to detect throttling.