# Trying for days but nvidia-smi refuses to run on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, apt, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I installed a fresh build for Ubuntu 20.04, without secure boot and when I run
nvidia-smi, I get the following error:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Here are the articles I've tried to follow with and I've tried all those solutions:
https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2022/07/29/solved-nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/

[NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927199/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-ma)

These are my outputs:

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Then

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.86.01  Wed Oct 26 09:12:38 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

Then:

```
pkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64                   515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-515                       515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-515:amd64                515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-515:amd64                 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-515:amd64                 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-515:amd64                  515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64                   515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-515:amd64                     515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-46-generic 5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1+1              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-46 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-60-generic 5.15.0-60.66~20.04.1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-60 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-46-generic  5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1+1              amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-46-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-60-generic  5.15.0-60.66~20.04.1                amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-60-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-515                   515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-515                            515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-515                          515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-515                   515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-515                   515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.14                              all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-515                           515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18build1                          all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515              515.86.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Then

```
whereis nvidia
nvidia: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia /usr/lib/nvidia /usr/share/nvidia /usr/src/nvidia-515.86.01/nvidia
```

I've tried doing fresh installs at least 8 times already in 3 days :(

Could someone tell me how to fix this please I need help :(

Comment: Part of the error message. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running. You are not running the latest, maybe try that.

Comment: No I tried but it didnt work and think it's because the recc'ed drivers for this is the one I currently have installed. Using this guide to see the recommended drivers: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux @David